# Prove or disprove: if $\{b_{n}\}$ is a convergent sequence and $c_{n} = n(b_{n} - b_{n-1})$, then $\{c_{n}\}$ is a bounded sequence.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The question says:

Prove or disprove: if $\{b_{n}\}$ is a convergent sequence and $c_{n} = n(b_{n} - b_{n-1})$, then $\{c_{n}\}$ is a bounded sequence.

Could you please give me a hint? I am stucked.

Comment: $b_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}  \frac {(-1)^{k}} {\sqrt k}$ is a counter-example.

Comment: is $b_{n}$ multiplied by the summation?@KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. $b_n$ is a sum of $n$- terms.

Comment: okay it was appearing in a different way >>>>thank you @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  how do you think about the idea? could you provide more details please?

Comment: I wanted see if $b_n-b_{n-1}$ could be something like $\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$ so that $n(b_n-b_{n-1})$ would be unbounded. But then $b_n$ became the n-th partial sum of the series $\sum \frac 1 {\sqrt n}$ which makes $b_n \to \infty$. So I modified by inserting $\pm$ signs into the series. I hope this explanation helps.

Comment: If $b_n=0$ when $n$ is odd and $b_n=n^{-1/2}$ when $n$ is even, then $c_{n} = n(n^{-1/2})=\sqrt{n}$ when $n$ is even and $\sqrt{n}$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $$c_n=n(b_n-b_{n-1}),$$ then $$b_n-b_{n-1}=\frac{c_n}{n}.$$ Thus $$b_n-b_0=\sum_{k=1}^n(b_k-b_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{c_k}{k},$$ which implies that $$b_n=b_0+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{c_k}{k}.$$

Since $\{b_n\}$ is convergent, hence $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{c_k}{k}$ is also convergent, but $\{c_k\}$ is not necessarily convergent, even not necessarily bounded. Here is a counterexample. Consider $c_k=(-1)^{k}\sqrt{k}$, which is not convergent and not bounded. But the alternating series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{c_k}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}=(\sqrt{2}-1)\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-0.604899\cdots$$

Comment: I am not understanding from where the first term on the right in the line after the word thus came ..... also I am not understanding the intuition behind your solution .... what makes you choose $c_{k}$ like this?

Answer (score 1):

False. Let $A=\{m^2: m\in \mathbb N\}.$ Define $b_n = 1/\sqrt n$ if $n\in A,$ $b_n=0$ otherwise. Then $b_n\to 0.$ But let's observe what happens to $n(b_n - b_{n-1})$ as $n\to \infty$ within $A.$ For such $n,$

$$n(b_n - b_{n-1}) = m^2(1/m -0) = m\to \infty.$$

Thus $n(b_n - b_{n-1})$ is unbounded.

Comment: what is the intuition behind your answer ..... you are searching for what?

Comment: Can you answer my comment under the first answer please?

Comment: The main idea is that there are plenty of sequences $a_n$ that tend to $0,$ while $na_n$ can be unbounded. Example: $a_n = 1/\sqrt n.$ So let's look for a convergent sequence $b_n$ such that $b_n-b_{n-1} = 1/\sqrt n. $ That won't work! However, don't give up: it might be possible to find a convergent $b_n$ such that $b_n - b_{n-1} = 1/\sqrt n$ for infinitely many $n.$ That's what I did.

Comment: How did you calculate $b_{n-1}$? I could not understand how it equals 0.

Comment: The sequence is $1,0,0,1/2,0,0,0,0,1/3,0,0,0,0,0,0,1/4,0 \dots$ So when we encounter a nonzero $b_n$ the term before it, $b_{n-1},$ is $0.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_n=0$ when $n$ is even and let $b_n=1/\sqrt n$ when $n$ is odd. Then $b_n$ converges to $0$ but $c_n=\sqrt  n$ for all odd $n.$

Comment: How is $c_{n} = \sqrt{n}$ for all odd $n$? the calculations with me does not give me this ....... how $n$ being odd will affect calculation?

Comment: When $n$ is odd, $b_n=1/\sqrt n$ and $b_{n-1}=0$ so $c_n=n(b_n-b_{n-1})=n(1/\sqrt n -0)=\sqrt n.$

Comment: Something wrong in your writing in the above comment ..... could you please adjust it?

Comment: I always make typos and have to edit and re-edit

Comment: A more interesting Q would be to restrict $b_n$ to  monotonic.